# When I run a git hook in a repo on a network share: which binaries are used?

Tags: networking, git, perl, hook

See title. My repo is located on a network share. When I push new revs there, a `post-udpate` hook is run. The hook needs Perl and runs nicely.

But which `perl.exe` is used here? The one on my machine? Or is Perl accidently installed on the remote machine and that Perl is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it’s a regular (SMB/CIFS) network share, it’s executed on the client.

If you use Git via SSH or HTTPS, Git (possibly an alternative implementation) is running on the remote side and executes hooks.

More simplified: If you have a file path set as the remote, it’s executed locally, even when it’s actually SSHFS or whatnot. Otherwise, it’s executed remotely.